# how to read a file in angular4 using file reader

Tags: angular, filereader

I was trying to find a way to read a file which user selects by clicking file choose button.
    
When he selects the file it will have number of rows and I want to read line by line. There are different ways using jquery, javascript. Does angular4 provide any tool. Could anybody give some samples or thoughts.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use a javascript solution with Angular? Angular is a JavaScript framework. It runs in your browser, as any other JavaScript application.

Comment: I don't mind a js solution too. any sample links?

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api is one of the many links returned when googling.

Comment: thanks!. I just gave a glance and this should give a solution.